# Caching on AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

So here's the deal. I recently started using AFNetworking to download a few files on start using the following code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* rq = [api requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"YOUR/URL/TO/FILE"     parameters:nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:rq] autorelease];

NSString* path=[@"/PATH/TO/APP" stringByAppendingPathComponent: imageNameToDisk];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"SUCCCESSFULL IMG RETRIEVE to %@!",path)

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    // Deal with failure
}];
```

With my path actually plugged into the path variable (Sorry, not on the right computer right now to actually copy pasta the text, but it's exactly the same as the above with different path stuffs)

And everything is working great! I'm  getting the file successfully downloaded and everything. My current issue is that I'm trying to get caching to work, but I'm having a lot of difficulties. Basically, I'm not sure what I actually have to *do* client side as of AFNetworking 2.0. Do I still need to set up the NSURlCache? Do I need to set the caching type header on the request operation differently? I thought that maybe it was just *entirely* built in, but I'm receiving a status of 200 every time the code runs, even with no changes in the file. If I do have to use the NSUrlCache, do I have to manually save the e-tag on the success blocks requestoperation myself and then feed that back in? Any help on how to progress would be much appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: the default url request's cachePolicy should work AFAIK -- you're sure the server is allowing caching?

Comment: try setting the caching policy explicitly of your request operation

Comment: So if I'm understanding you guys correctly, it should cache with 0 extra from what I put in above, yeah? And obviously I should get a 304 on the success blocks operation yeah?

Comment: @AlexSullivan I think the cached object is returned in the success block, so you won't see the 304, you'll see the 200 returned on the original request that was cached.

Comment: 304 is considered a "success" in the HTTP world, but I have been getting a 304 in the failure block.

Comment: This should work. If you need to determine if response was returned from the server or from cache, you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21556002/514181

Answer (score 4):

AFNetworking uses NSURLCache for caching by default.  From [the FAQ](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ):

> AFNetworking takes advantage of the caching functionality already provided by `NSURLCache` and any of its subclasses. So long as your `NSURLRequest` objects have the correct cache policy, and your server response contains a valid `Cache-Control` header, responses will be automatically cached for subsequent requests.

Note that this mechanism caches `NSData`, so every time you retrieve from this cache you need to perform a somewhat expensive `NSData`-to-`UIImage` operation.  This is not performant enough for rapid display, for example if you're showing images in a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`.

If this is the case, look at [`UIImageView+AFNetworking`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html), which adds downloads and caching of `UIImage` objects to `UIImageView`.  For some applications you can just use the out-of-the-box implementation, but it is very basic.  You may want to look at the source code for this class (it's not very long) and use it as a starting point for your own caching mechanism.

Comment: Also: SDWebImage is a more robust image downloading, caching, and display library, but it doesn't integrate with AFNetworking: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage