# Using NSURLCache to display data quickly, update in background

Tags: ios, caching, nsurlrequest, nsurlcache

I'd like my iOS application (at least certain endpoints) to have the following network behavior:

- Always use the cache, whenever it's available, no matter the age (draw the UI right away)
- If the data is stale, also make a network request (the UI has stale data during this period, but it's still probably pretty close)
- If network data returns, update the cache and make any UI updates that are required.

I prefer a behavior like this because I can then set my caching policy very aggressively (long cache times). For data that updates infrequently, this results in rapid UI returns in the common case and a model layer that is kept up to date essentially in the background (from the user's perspective)

I'm reading about [NSURLCache](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/), but I don't see a cache policy, or even a combination of two policies that I'm confident in.

Options:

1. Use `ReturnCacheDataDontLoad` to always get cache. If failure or old cache use `ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` for the HTTP fetch. (have to check myself? age is inspectable?)
2. Use `ReturnCacheDataDontLoad` to always get cache. Then use `UseProtocolCachePolicy` with the cache time set to very low and ignore the response if it returns from cache (can I tell if it returns from cache? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12244125/111243) says not reliably)
3. Separate the two concerns. Use `ReturnCacheDataDontLoad` for all user-initiated requests, only firing a network request right away if there is no cache at all. Separately, have a worker that keeps an eye on stored models, updating them in the background whenever they appear old.
4. Extend NSURLCache
5. Use something OTS that already does this? (-[AFNetworking just uses NSURLSession caching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19915548/111243). +[EVURLCache](https://github.com/evermeer/EVURLCache) forces disk caching but expects the data to be seeded on app install.

Comment: Did you end up extending NSURLCache? I'm looking to do something similar, where I use cache then load network data. Parse queries do just that

Comment: I didn't find a good solution, though I started on a model caching library. I'm glad others are interested in this problem too. I am not interested in adopting something as broad as Parse though.