# X-Auth-Token Invalid After 1 Session

Tags: ios, xcode, api, networking, afnetworking

I'm developing an iOS App in Xcode and using AFNetworking to talk to the API - the API uses "X-Auth-Token". So when I log in and store the session token in the User Defaults, it works perfectly until the app is restarted - the session token doesn't work then for some reason?

The token is used in AFNetworking like so:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setValue:@"SessionTokenFromUserDefaults" forKey:@"X-Auth-Token"];
```

Does anyone have any advice? (PS: the error I get from AFN when using the token after restarting is: Request failed: unauthorized (401)

How could I acheive this without logging in each session?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I remember having that sort of problems using NSURLConnections without a cache policy.
I think there is a [thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180727/afnetworking-how-to-know-if-response-is-using-cache-or-not-304-or-200) that might help.

Comment: Hi, I got this response: http://pastebin.com/aVL5euzY - any suggestions? thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the server report Request failed: unauthorized (401) is because the token is empty.

To debug, You can add these two lines in your AppDelegate's

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[AFNetworkActivityLogger sharedLogger] startLogging];
    [[AFNetworkActivityLogger sharedLogger] setLevel:AFLoggerLevelDebug];
}
```

Then you can check the request in your log to see if the token has actually been set in the header.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem - here is what I used:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:sessionToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];
```